# Difference-in-Difference with multiple regression vs. matching combined with Difference in Difference

Tags: multiple-regression, propensity-scores, difference-in-difference, matching

I want to use a Difference-in-Difference approach. In order to make sure treatment and control group are similar, I want to use a propensity score matching before the DiD approach. What I do is to make sure that the observables of both groups are similar. 
But what if I just skip the PSM and just control for all relevant observables if estimating the DiD as multiple regression? Is there a difference in outcome?

Would be great to get an explanation. Thank you.